# How to check if mouse is pressed on JComponent

Tags: java, jcomponent

I have a JComponent, and I want it do preform a piece of code when the component is pressed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
JComponent comp = new JPanel();
comp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // Place your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: In place where you create your component.

Comment: My file that extends JComponent?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t90tcLv9 where `new Line("hi");` is a System.out.println("hi"); Basicly, it doesn't output "hi".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Class that extends JComponent

```
import java.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MyClass extends JComponent{
    public MyClass(){

        //Other code

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // Place your code here
            }
        });

        //Other code
    }
}
```